# For a List<A> containing List<B> , How do I change the values inside B and return the modified List<A> using RxJava2?

Tags: android, rx-java2, dagger-2, rx-android, android-mvp

I am trying to implement rxandroid in MVP pattern, 
This is my usecase:

**A.class**

```
   List<B> b;

   List<B> getB(){
       return b;
   }
```

**B.class**

```
String dataTochange;

void  setDataToChange(String dataToChange){
      this.dataToChange = dataToChange
   }
```

I want to return same *Observable(List (A))* after changing the value inside B.

This is what I have done,

**REMOTEDATASOURCE.java:**

```
Observable<List<A>> getAList(){
    return FromApiService
                 .getAList()                   // returns List<A> 
                 .flatMapIterable(List<A>  ->  A )
                 .map(A::getB)
                 .flatMapIterable(List<B> b ->  b)
                 .map(b -> doSomeDownloading(b))
       //After this i want to return the modified 
     List<A> containing list of B with dataChanged.            

 }



   doSomeDownloading(B b){

   somValue = doAsynchronousDownload(b)

   b.setDataToChange(somValue);

 }


 doAsynchronousDownload(B b){

 contains callbacks to listeners implemented by View for progress etc;

 }
```

Structure of the repository:

[image: enter link description here]

PS: Is the implementation logic right, the downloading should be done in presenter. or inside the repository!

**Update**

```
serviceApi.getAList()
          .flatMapIterable(List<A> -> a)
                  .flatMap(A a ->
                         Observable.fromIterable(a.getB())
                         .doOnNext(b ->doSomeDownloading(b))
                         .toList()
                         .toObservable()
                         .map(new Function<List<B>, A>() {
                             @Override
                             public A apply(List<B> b) throws Exception 
                               {
                                 a.setB(b);
                                 return a;
                             }
                         })
                  )
                .toList()
                .toObservable()
                .doOnSubscribe(...)
```

Doing above shows, **result of doSomeDownloading() is ignored** ..

Comment: What you mean by result of doSomeDownloading() is ignored? If your doSomeDownloading() is just a downloading work without changing any value of B. Then the above code should work. But if you want to doSomeDownloading() and then return a new B. Then you should use a `map` instead of `doOnNext`

Comment: @PhoenixWang ...my bad.!!..i had some bad logic issues inside the doSomeDownloading method  ..Now its working as intended..thanks a lot  for the help!

Comment: @PhoenixWang ..hi ..in the above case what if my **doSomeDownloading** happens to be a recursive asynchronous function eg: **doSomeDownloding(List<B>) **... and after all the requests get completed , i pass in the list to (onNext) of the  **subscribe**     ,is that possible!!

Comment: definitely possible and code could be much shorter in RxJava. You don't need those `toList()` and `flatMapIterable()`. Only thing you kept will be the `flatMap`

Comment: @PhoenixWang...i am finding very difficult to implement that!! ..could you help me in chat... the problem is before requests get completed *subscribe*  onNext  is called...!! would be of great help if you could share some samples!

Comment: update your post or make a new question to describe it then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really depends on how you transform the A into List and how you will do with it.
If your transformation is simple(means they are not time/resource consuming process). You could just use a flatMap to "cache" your values
ex:

```
FromApiService.getAList()
              .flatMapIterable(List<A>  ->  A)
              .flatMap{a:A -> 
                   Observable.fromIterable(a.getB())
                             .doOnNext{b -> doSomeDownloading(b)}//or Map/FlatMap if you want
                             .toList()
                             .toObservable()//here you have your new list<B>
                             .map{b -> a.setB(b)}//here you get your A
               }
```

Comment: ..hi... **doSomeDownloading** is time consuming  i guess, since the file needs to be downloaded  asynchronously..!! after that list needs to be transformed and added to A ...

Comment: @rdk1234 it doesn't matter doSomeThingLoading does. You can use this code if your getB() is not time consuming.

Comment: hi..the last line  **map{b -> a.setB(b)}**  complains of **bad return type:void cannot be converted to object**.!!

Comment: @rdk1234. Yes i forgot. you should return A after bind your new B to A

Comment: ..i have written the following.       `.map(new Funtion(List<B> b , A )
                      @override
                     A apply(List<B> b){
                     a.setB(b);
                  return a;
                })
             )
.toList
.toObservable()`   ....doing above shows **doSomeDownloading(b)** is ignored!!